# How to avoid new between text fields on Rails 3

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3

I can remove the new line 
 between label/text_field by display:inline ,
however, it dens't work on text filed. is there anyway to fix my problem ?

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name, '書名', :style => "display:inline;" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :style => "display:inline;" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label  :isbn, 'isbn'.upcase , :style => "display:inline;" %>
    <%= f.text_field :isbn, {:onkeyup=>"if (event.keyCode == 13) {add_book()}"} %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try left float like this:

```
.field {
  float: left;
}
```